# RecyclerView fill empty space inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

### Background

I have a header and footer (`LinearLayout`) with a `RecyclerView` between them.

### The problem

I need that the footer stay fixed at the bottom of the screen and the `RecyclerView` fills the empty space

[image]

### What I've tried

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="br.com.sigane.coletordifal.activity.EnderecamentoActivity">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Header" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                  android:id="@+id/produtos_list"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Footer" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also tried to use `ConstraintLayout`, but without success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Add  `android:layout_height="0dp"` and [`android:layout_weight="1"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_weight) to the `RecyclerView`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/produtos_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Footer" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to have separate linear layouts. I think just one is enough. Just set your weights like this for your recyclerview and footer.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/produtos_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Footer" />
```

Comment: This code that I put in the question is just an example.
I have removed the linear layout from the header

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the constraint layout, it is a FrameLayout on steroids. If you are using android studio 3.2, right-clicking on the root element in the design view shows a menu with the option "convert to constraintlayout"

The reason you do not want to nest layouts like this, Each nested element results in additional measure passes, nested layouts are messy and harder to inflate than flat layouts.

Highly recommend spending an hour or so reading about the constraint layout and how to use it. You will not regret it, helped my improve productivity by 2x.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: ConstraintLayout is FrameLayout on steroids? Buddy, you confused the tagline of google's CoordinatorLayout with Constraintlayout

Comment: the constraintlayout is very similar to a frame layout in the sense of, we have to give it locations like u would with the frame layout.

Comment: Ummm ... no! Dude read source of CoordinatorLayout. It actually is FrameLayout. ConstraintLayout is more similar to RelativeLayout. In fact, it's a replacement for RelativeLayout.

Comment: ur argument is what exactly it almost feels like u are arguing for arguments sake, I did not state anything about extension im simply talking about behavior, im done with this conversation its not helping the question at hand. Please maintain decorum in the discussion.